# Positioning Image in next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I want to make my Image on the most right of the page, I try to modify with `position: absolute` and `right: 0`.
I also try to make parent position to relative, and image position to absolute, but why it doesn't work?

here's in my jsx file

```
        <div className={styles.images}>
          <Image
            src="/cloud.svg"
            alt="Picture of the author"
            layout="fill"
            className={styles.cloud}
          />
          <Image
            src="/kuil.svg"
            alt="Picture of the author"
            height={200}
            width={600}
            layout="intrinsic"
            className={styles.building}
          />
        </div>
```

Also in my css file.

```
.images {
    position: relative;
    margin: 90px auto 0 auto;
}

.building {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: please confirm its working . you defined the className with `styles` as js object . Then how will css work. you need use Dom css object instead of normal css

Comment: @prasanth He's probably using CSS Modules, `styles.images` returns a string.

Comment: What a beautiful image!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had also encountered same problem. The Image tag when compiled wrap the img tag with a div tag of style position relative.

The solution is to simply wrap Image tag with div and add classname to the div.

check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-image-tag-absolute-styling-4s0d7?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: I've been seeing this solution EVERYWHERE and it's not working at all for me :( The only way I can absolutely position PNG/SVG images is using <img> which it shows warnings about and says I cannot use it (I assume theyre not optimized for the Static HTML Export I'm using/NextJS period). I really really need to be able to move images wherever I want on the screen and I cannot figure out how to do it within this limited and quite annoying <Image/> component in NextJS... it takes away so much of the functionality I need/learned to use

Comment: It will be helpful if you share a reproducible example.

Comment: I solved the issue by asking the designer to simply export the entire Sketch design as a single image to be used as a backgroundImage instead of expecting me to absolutely position everything she did with a mouse ;)

Answer (score 3):

## **October 2022:**

Looks like Vercel are moving forward with a better implementation that removes the wrapper from the `<img />` tag

#### To access this feature you must import from a new path:

`import Image from 'next/future/image';`

and then in your `next.config.js` file add the new flag:

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    images: {
      allowFutureImage: true,
    },
  },
};
```

Now your images are free. No longer wrapped in anything!

Beware: The API may change in future NextJS updates.

Comment: As of today, this solution triggers a warning: `- warn Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
- warn The value at .experimental has an unexpected property, images, which is not in the list of allowed properties`

Answer (score 2):

There's now a more convenient way to have full control of how your Images are positioned in Nextjs:

First: It's currently experimental, so to have it work you have to enable it in your next.config.js file.

example:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    images: {
      layoutRaw: true,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Secondly: Use `layout` prop of the Image to 'raw'

example:

```js
<Image
   src={ImageSource}
   alt={'description here'}
   layout={'raw'}
   ...
/>
```

So you can now style your Image as you wished.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it has been again removed for now. `v12.2.0 Experimental remotePatterns and experimental unoptimized configuration added. layout="raw" removed.`

Comment: It's been moved, not removed. It is now a future feature of the image module! :) I added an answer to address this.